# Switch button to turn on notifications

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, push-notification

hope you could help me here!
I want to make a switch button that turns on a function of push daily push notification. how do I do that?

the switch button is on the Settings fragment

My MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    displayView(R.id.nav_home);



}


@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return;
    }

    if (getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.content_main) instanceof Article) {
        ((Article) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.content_main)).handleOnBackPress();
        return;
    }

    if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() == 0) {
        displayView(R.id.nav_home);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();

    }
}

private void displayView(int itemId) {
    Fragment fragment = null;

    switch (itemId) {
        case R.id.nav_home:
            fragment = new Article();
            break;
        case R.id.nav_Recipes:
            fragment = new RecipesMain();
            break;
        case R.id.nav_Converter:
            fragment = new Converter();
            break;
        case R.id.nav_Videos:
            fragment = new Videos();
            break;
        case R.id.nav_Tracking:
            fragment = new Tracking();
            break;
        case R.id.nav_TrainerMenu:
            fragment = new TrainerMenu();
            break;
        case R.id.nav_Settings:
            fragment = new Settings();
            break;
        case R.id.nav_About:
            showDialog();
            break;

    }


    if (fragment != null) {
        final Fragment finalFragment = fragment;
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                getSupportFragmentManager()
                        .beginTransaction()
                        .setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.slide_in_left, android.R.anim.slide_out_right)
                        .replace(R.id.content_main, finalFragment)
                        .commit();
            }
        }, 0);
            }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    }




@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    displayView(item.getItemId());
    return true;
}
private void showDialog()
{
    String text2 = "<font color=#6774bd>About SG50 App</font>";

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this, R.style.AppCompatAlertDialogStyle);
    builder.setTitle(Html.fromHtml(text2));

    String text3 = "<font color=#A4A4A4>App made by Matan Cohen , Please contact me for any questions.</font>";//for custom message
    builder.setMessage(Html.fromHtml(text3));

    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
        {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "תודה על שימוש", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
            toast.show();
        }
    });

    builder.show();
 }

}
```

fragment Settings.java **the "editor.getBoolean" gives me cannot resolve error!! what can I do?**:

```
public class Settings extends Fragment {

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_settings, container, false);

}


@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    getActivity().setTitle("הגדרות");

    Switch aSwitch = (Switch) getView().findViewById(R.id.dailyTipSwitch);
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("key", 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putBoolean("switchValue", aSwitch.isChecked());
    editor.apply();
    boolean showNotifications = editor.getBoolean("key",false);
            if (aSwitch.isChecked() != showNotifications) {
                editor.putBoolean("key",!showNotifications).apply();
            }
            else {
                Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,19);
                calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,27);
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),NotificationReciever.class);
                PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),100,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getActivity().getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
                alarmManager.setRepeating(alarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,calendar.getTimeInMillis(),AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,pendingIntent);
            }


    }

}
```

Notification_Reciever.java

```
public class NotificationReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Intent repeatingIntent = new Intent(context,MainActivity.class);
    repeatingIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,100,repeatingIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);



    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new
            NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText("בוקר טוב אלוף! תאכל ותשתה טוב!"))
            .setContentText(context.getString(R.string.NotificationText))
            .setContentTitle(context.getString(R.string.GoodMorningNotification))
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setAutoCancel(true);

    notificationManager.notify(100, mBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

fragemnt_settings.XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="30dp"
android:paddingBottom="30dp"
android:paddingTop="30dp"
android:paddingRight="30dp">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <Switch
        android:id="@+id/switch1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:layout_gravity="left" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:text="@string/daily_tip"
        android:textSize="20sp"/>
</LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Thank you!! Hope you can help me!

THE editor.getBoolean GIVES ME CANNOT RESOLVE ERROR!!!
what Can I do???

Comment: I assume that you want somebody to just do this instead of you, but it doesn't work this way. So you need to save a value of the switch somewhere (true of false), and check it before showing notification. If the value is true, then show it. Otherwise - no

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to save the value of the switch somewhere(SQLite or SharedPreferences) and check if it is the current switch value, than change the value in the place you keep it **on switch checked or unchecked**

this is how you create SharedPreferences and put in a value:

```
 SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("key", 0);
 SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
 editor.putBoolean("switchValue", aSwitch.isChecked());
 editor.apply();
```

this is how you check the SharedPreferences value and change it:

```
 Boolean showNotifications = editor.getBoolean("key",false);
 if (aSwitch.isChecked() != showNotifications) {
                editor.putBoolean("key",!showNotifications).apply();
            }
```

where you want to notify a notification you should check the SharedPreferences value:

```
Boolean showNotifications = editor.getBoolean("key",false);
```

**edited** This is how you fire a notifications:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new  
NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.your_drawable)
                    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText("notification text"))
                    .setContentText(notificationToNotify.getText())
                    .setContentTitle(CaseFormat.UPPER_UNDERSCORE.to(CaseFormat.UPPER_CAMEL, "notification title"))
                    .setContentIntent(contentPendingIntent)
                    .setDeleteIntent(deletePendingIntent)
                    .setAutoCancel(true);

            //notify the Notification
            mNotifyMgr.notify(notification_id, mBuilder.build());
```

notification_id - int id you can give to every notification.
you can set delete intent and content intent(if the user clicks on the notification)

Man you need to use the same "key". like that:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = 
getActivity().getSharedPreferences("key", 0);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
editor.putBoolean("**switchValue**", aSwitch.isChecked());
editor.apply();
boolean showNotifications = 
editor.getBoolean("**switchValue**",false);
```

Comment: Yeah this is supposed to do it but how do I make the notification itself? haha

Comment: You can check every onResume or onCreate of MainActivity and if the user wants notifications. is so - fire him.

Comment: Thank you so much, I'll try that and give you the confirm later!

Comment: Hey, can't get the 'editor.getBoolean' its says it cannot resolve that
doing it in fragment

Comment: Did you write: SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("key", 0);
 SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
  before you used editor?

Comment: Edited the question

Answer (score 1):

If understand correctly, the issue here is not about how to know if the switch is turned on or off, but about avoiding getting push notifications according to switch state.

You want to avoid getting the notification and NOT - get the notification and decide whether to present it or not.

So what you need is to save switch state as mentioned in other answers, but in addition - If the user switched the state to OFF you need to unregister the user from getting the notifications and vice versa, using the following:

Either delete the token from the server which holds the user's FCM token:

```
// Remove user from notification messages
InstanceID.getInstance(context).deleteInstanceID();

// Register user back to get notifications
FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken() // This will call the onTokenRefresh() method which will call your implementation that calls your FCM server and update the new user's token
```

Or if this user is registered to a specific notification topic

```
// Unregister him from the topic
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().unsubscribeToTopic("news");

// Register him back in case switch is on
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("news");
```

Comment: Yeah this is supposed to do it but how do I make the notification itself? haha

Comment: I f you are asking how to send / not send notification from the sever side
you will need to add here which server side technology you are using (NodeJS, PHP, C#, Java etc.) and then you will be able to be assisted - but this seems like another question.

Answer (score 0):

```java
boolean showNotifications = editor.getBoolean("key",false);
```

To

```
boolean showNotifications = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("key",false);
```